Often Misused: File Upload - Fortify
<input id="field" name="upload" type="file" />

Fortify flagged the above line of code and indicated as Medium Priority, with the title, Often Misused: File Upload.
The recommendation indicated that

Do not allow file uploads if they can be avoided. If a program must
accept file upoads, then restrict the abilitiy of an attacker to
supply malicious content by only accepting the specific types of
content the program expects. Most attacks that rely on uploaded
content require that attackers be able to supply content of their
choosing. Placing restrictions on the content the program will accept
will greatly limit the range of possible attacks. Check file names,
extension and file content to make sure they are all expected and
acceptable for use by the application.

I did the check file names, extension and file content in the form submit action, but the fortify still flagged out. May I know what is the right fix for this flagged out?

This is a warning, not a bug. Just mark it acknowledged after you've done the checks. There is no fix that fortify can automatically detect.
